# Is it necessary to clean and build entire project when i change i java file in my project in netbeans editor

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been doing a project in java for the last one year. When I started the project, it was small. But now it is growing as a big project, so my question is, is it necessary to clean and build my entire project when I do a change in my java file. Is there any other way to get my change on the source file when I build only the file that I have updated finally? I am using netbeans for editing the files in my project. When I use the function `compile on save` the entire working is making it very slow.

Answer (score 0):

It's a balance between the clean/build (slow to rune) or "compile on save" (fast to run).

You look at breaking you project down into small chunks, taking those parts that are complete or change rarely and compile them into Jar's and import those Jar's into you project.  This way you won't need to compile code that hasn't changed.

The downside is it come the management a little more complicated, as when ever you change one of these libraries, you need to remember to copy into it's link-in location - don't link directly to the `dist/jar` as this could have the potential to lock the file, make new builds impossible.